# Prove that the entire function $f$ is linear.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

**Suppose $f=u+iv$ be an entire function such that $u(x,y)=\phi(x)$ and $v(x,y)=\psi(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f(x)=az+b$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C},b\in\mathbb{C}$.**

My approach was: $u(x,y)=\phi(x)\Rightarrow\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\phi'(x),\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$. Now $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)=0$. Now $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0$, implying $f$ is constant.

**Where did I go wrong?**

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann equations are generally stated as
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &= - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{align*}
Where did you get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ from?

Comment: @Singhal  If a complex-valued function $f$ is holomorphic then, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Of course I made a mistake in mentioning that I have used CR equations, I have edited it. Now how do I solve the problem.

Comment: Well, that is for complex function and $u$ is real function.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was the point. For a holomorphic function $f$, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =: \frac{df}{dz}$ but the same is not true for its real part $u$.

Comment: @Singhal  OK, then, how do I find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ then? And how can I solve the problem?

Comment: To solve it use $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$.

Comment: @GEdgar You mean, I need to use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$?

Comment: No, I mean use the C-R equations as given by Singhal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy-Riemann equations ($u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=v_x$) provide:
$$
u_x=\varphi'(x)=\psi'(y)=v_y
$$
Thus $\varphi'(x)=c=\psi'(y)$, and hence
$$
\varphi(x)=cx+a,\quad \psi(y)=cy+b,
$$
and finally
$$
f(z)=cz+a+bi.
$$

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't need to find $\dfrac{du}{dz}$ in this case. Instead, let's look at $\dfrac{df}{dz} := \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \phi' (x)$, a real-valued holomorphic function as derivatives of holomorphic functions are holomorphic too. The only real-valued holomorphic functions are the constant functions. Thus, we have that $f'(z) \equiv a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, $f(z) = az + b$ for some $a \in \Bbb{R}, b \in \Bbb{C}$.